# Is it possible to outline the text in a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, outline, txt

The question is in the title.

Here's my code :

```
JButton button = new JButton("JOUER", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("template.png")));
button.setBounds(0, 0, 215, 84);
button.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
button.setFont(new Font("Bebas Neue Bold", Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 50));
button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
button.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
button.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Here's the result :

[image: The result]

And I just want to know if is it possible to outline my text.

Here's the result I want to have:

[image: The button I want to have]

Comment: So you want to outline your button, but the "[button you want to have](https://www.zupimages.net/up/20/48/7ods.png)" does not have an outline. Which is it?

Comment: Images should be uploaded to this site so they are visible with your question.

Comment: Maybe something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028358/change-jbutton-focus-area/24028405#24028405

Comment: The appearance of raised text has to be part of the font.  Otherwise, you can try [Outline Font paint](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/OutlineFontpaint.htm).